# some questions about react engine worker

Tags: reactjs, reconciliation

I have two question about react reconciliation,
First step is do study more about it for best start learning react ,
Second step is that need I everything know about react engine for start learning react
Help me by your offers
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Learning React you must have basic knowledge about javascript then you can  learn about react engine and how react works from documentation.

Comment: Which one package is nessery in first I must learn ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the know about basic JavaScript you first know how react engine work and know about best practices for solve hard challenge in projects,
So first start study advance concept reactjs then study basic react documentation